# Lapply function to a list stops after the first item

Tags: r

I am using the following function to convert a list of address to gps coordinates:

```
geocodeAdddress <- function(address) {
  url <- "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="
  url <- URLencode(paste(url, address, "&sensor=false", sep = ""))
  x <- fromJSON(url, simplify = FALSE)
  if (x$status == "OK") {
    out <- c(x$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lng,
             x$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lat)
  } else {
    out <- NA
  }
  Sys.sleep(0.2)  # API only allows 5 requests per second
  out
}
```

Once I use the following lapply to the list I only get one result and not the complete list:

```
mylist <-read.table('my.csv',sep=",",allowEscapes=TRUE)
latlonglist <- lapply(mylist,geocodeAdddress)
```

I tried a for loop and did not work either. Any ideas would be great. Thanks

Update her in pseudocode or as much as I know so far what I would liek to achieve:

Create empty data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 0))
x <- c("longitude", "latitude")
colnames(df) <- x
```

Loop through your list:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(mylist)) {
  all = geocodeAdddress(mylist[i, ])
  Pseudo code:  
  everything before space long = strsplit(all, " ")
  everything after space  lat = strsplit(all, " ")
  long append data.frame(longitude)
  lat append data.frame(longitude)
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that `lapply` loops over the columns of the table (and not over the rows)?

Comment: No, Thanks for that. Makes sense that it does not work. How can I loop over rows ?

Comment: You should be able to use `apply(mylist, 1, geocodeAdddress)`. The `1` indicates that the function should be applied over rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments: `lapply` loops over the columns and not over the rows. You could use a `for` loop to call the function for each row:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(mylist)) {
  geocodeAdddress(mylist[i, ])
}
```

Note that `mylist[i, ]` selects the whole `i-th` row. If you want the **value** in the first column you would use `mylist[i, 1]`

---

Update on how to store the data in the data frame:

First, I would preallocate the whole data.frame at once instead of adding a row each time. You can do it like this:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = nrow(mylist)))
x <- c("longitude", "latitude")
colnames(df) <- x
```

Second, I think you do not need stringsplit here at all. The function `geocodeAdddress` does not return a single string, but instead a vector of two strings. You can then just assign the result in the loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(mylist)) {
  df[i, ] <- geocodeAdddress(mylist[i, ])
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works, but how can i assign it to a data.frame. Ideally this would split along the space and put it into two columns "longitude", "latitude".

Comment: Use `strsplit` to split the result at the space. Create "dummy" vectors before the `for`-loop like `latitude <- rep(NA, nrow(mylist))`. You can then assign the values within the loop by `latitude[i] <- RESULT_OF_STRSPLIT`

Comment: I tried this but don't seem to understand this very well. Even though it seemed simple. I would like to create a data.frame and append the two values I get from strsplit into each one column and then go to the next row. Sorry for not solving this by what you suggested.

Comment: Could you post a working code example? It is hard to talk about things I cannot try out :)

Comment: I tried to write what I would like to achieve as a combo of pseudo code and real code in my original answer. Hope that it makes it clearer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I updated my answer. On a sidenote: I can still not reproduce, because I do not have my.csv

Comment: This worked. Even tough I don't fully understand it. Because it seems to me it just should copy the first value but it does copy both. Genius ! Thanks.